# Python Social Auth - Facebook Auth API v2.5

Tags: python, facebook, authentication, oauth, python-social-auth

I'm using python-social-auth. On June I've created the app on developers.facebook.com. Facebook's api version is v2.2. Everything is working.
Additionally my user model using email as username so I defined in settings.py SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email'].

Today I've created new app on developers.facebook.com, api version is v2.5. Configuration of app is the same like in my v2.2 app. There is a problem. After redirect from facebook.com, Im using create_user() to create user. I don't know why I've know user data (email, gender, etc) I've only UID, first name and second name.

Of course Im testing social authentication in one www project.

It may be the fault of Facebook App Update?

Comment: Most likely the API v2.4 change, “declarative fields” – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes Your app must now explicitly list the fields it is interested in when making API requests – so your request that fetches the user details likely will need to be modified.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I've to declare this fields on developers.facebook.com app's stetting or in my www project?

Comment: You need to ask for the fields in your code at the point where the request for the user details is made. (Check with PSA if they don’t have an update already that incorporates these changes.)

Comment: Ok, many thanks @CBroe